# How can I encapsulate the idea of 'all parameters' in F#?

Tags: f#

In F#, I need to do something like this:

```
let price k s t r v =
  let d1 = d1 k s t r v
... and so on
```

I'm getting really tired of listing all the parameters when they are passed into a function. Apart from turning the parameters into a parameter object (something I *cannot* do), is there any way to group the parameters? I'm thinking of something like

```
let price (k s t r v as foo) =
  let d1 = d1 foo
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of `foo`? What is the type of `d1`? Your code is currently inconsistent.

Comment: I would just use tuples or records if the collection of the parameters has any common name. Any reason why you cannot use them?

Comment: @OldrichSvec this function is also used in curve fitting where creating temporary tuple objects all the time wastes too much heap space.

Comment: So, what about structs? But it would be interesting to see the real impact of the tuple construction on the performance of your code ;)

Comment: Ugh, I don't really want to go there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can effectively batch together your arguments (call them `w, x, y, z`) via a higher-order function like so

```
let batchedArgs f = f w x y z
```

Now `batchedArgs` is a closure over the original function arguments.  You just pass it another function which takes the same number/type of arguments, and they will be applied.

```
// other functions which you wish to pass the args to
let sub1 w x y z = 42
let sub2 w x y z = true

// main routine
let doStuff w x y z =
    // one-time declaration of batching function is
    // the only time you need to list out the arguments
    let batchedArgs f = f w x y z

    // from then on, invoke like this
    batchedArgs sub1
    // or like this, which looks more like a traditional function call
    sub2 |> batchedArgs
```

Comment: Note that marking `batchedArgs` as `inline` might be desirable if you are really worried about too much object generation.